# MySQL, Concatenate columns

Tags: sql, mysql

A shipping company's control panel needs a query that return a list of all customers with information about their packages, grouped by status.

The result should have the following columns: email/ created/ shipped/ delivered / on_hold / cancelled.

- email: customer email address;
- created, shipped, delivered, on_hold, cancelled: record format is ## - ##, where the placeholders are ## in order they appear:

1. The total **number of packages** of a specific customer and status;
2. The total **weight of packages** of a specific customer and status.

The result should be sorted in ascending way by email.

Note: The total weight of is the sum of the weights of all packages.

Pictures of schema, sample of output and expected output are below [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT3aB.jpg), [sample input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LADIH.jpg), [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReWTY.jpg)

I tried using the WITH clause to structure a base in terms of email, order weight and status. Later, I tried using the CONCAT function in the underlying query.

```
SELECT
email,
CASE
WHEN status = 'created' THEN CONCAT (COUNT(*), " = ", SUM(weight))
END as created
FROM base
GROUP BY 1
```

Same for other status, but didn't work. Someone could explain me how could I solve this problem?

Comment: **Do not post images of technical information** like sample data or results. People here want to be abe to test the code at a site like db fiddle before posting an answer, and if they have to retype everything they just **won't bother**, meaning you're unlikely to get a good answer at all. Instead, post it as **formatted text** they can copy paste into the test system.

Comment: Please repost all of those screenshots as text.  Actually it would be best if you took it one step further and created a db fiddle yourself.  I suspect I am not alone in having little patience for creating DB Fiddles for people.    Also "doesn't work" - make sure to include *actual* results, not just indication that they weren't what you desired.

Comment: You said it's supposed to be grouped by status. But you don't have the status column in the SQL.